# The use of pioneering as a verb

Tags: word-choice

I am new to this forum, so please let me know if this question is unacceptable.

I want to say something like, "help model the world by pioneering with companies and originations of the highest order.". By this what I am trying to say is teaming up with different teams to pioneer new projects of theirs. Is the use of pioneering okay or incorrect?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Greetings, welcome!  This might be better suited for the English Language Learners SE, since it is about basic word definition and sentence construction

Comment: Is *originations* a typo for *organisations*? If not, U don't understand it. Personally I would ***not*** endorse this intransitive use of *pioneering*, and I think the sentence is already trying to cram in too many "positive association" phrases. To include yet another phrase defining exactly *what* is being pioneered would make it far too "busy". I'd settle for simpler phrasing, personally.

Answer (score 1):

Pioneering in respect of business ventures is something that is done in new technologies, not companies.  *Pioneering with companies* comes across as airheaded corporate-speak.  *Pioneering new technologies* on the other hand, actually means something, and it means that one is using existing technologies for new problems, new technologies for old problems, or something similar.

Another thing.  "help model the world" means what, exactly?  A model is a representation of something.  To model something in the textile or clothing industry would mean to wear an item to show off how it would look.  To model the world sounds like you plan to make the world take on the shape of a model it doesn't already have and sounds incredibly grandiose and full of hubris.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have used or heard *pioneer* as a verb is transitively, the object being the novelty, for example:

> Lister pioneered the use of vaccination.

I find *pioneer new projects* a little odd, because the effort and primacy implied by *pioneer* does not quite match the non-specific word *projects*; but it is not impossible. But *to pioneer with companies* conveys no meaning to me.